# Evaluating the limit of a function using multiple Macluarin series

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, fractions, limits-without-lhopital

While doing my usual homework-routine I came across a problem which I just can't seem to get my head around, probably missing some fundamental knowledge on the subject, or just not thinking straight.

Anyhow, the exercise is to evaluate the limit as x->0 of the function $\frac{(ln(1+x)-sin(x)-cos(x)+1)}{arctan(x)-x}$ using Maclaurin-expansion for each of the terms. That I have done, but I can't seem to get anywhere after some of the first terms in each series cancel out. I am left with one power series plus another, divided by a third... I know the answer is supposed to be $-3\over 2$.

If anyone would be so kind as to at least point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\ln(1+x)-\sin{x}-\cos{x}+1}{\arctan{x}-x}=$$
$$=\tfrac{\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}...\right)-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}...\right)-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...\right)+1}{x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-...-x}=$$
$$=\tfrac{\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)\right)-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)\right)+1}{x-\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)-x}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}{-\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{o(x^3)}{x^3}}{-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{o(x^3)}{x^3}}\rightarrow-\frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am getting the first part, however I don't understand the operation where the series converge into fractals, just applying the limit gives you a lovely 0/0-situation, so something must be happening that I am not seeing...

Comment: @Viktor I added something. See now.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, for the quick responses. I now realise I must learn the ways of the O-notation in order to understand this (again to the textbooks I go!).

Comment: Still not seeing where all this is coming from, and I fear the explaination I require is more thorough than I would ever ask anyone to write here. I don't see how you rewrite the sums in that way. Yes, I see that $\frac{x^3}{3}$ and $\frac{x^3}{6}$ are the first terms in two of the resulting series (ln(1+x) and -sin(x)-cos(x)) after cancellation of some terms, but there it ends... Again, thank you though!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Shouldn't you use $O(x^4)$ after the $x^3$ term?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Doesn't the $o(x)$ and $O(x)$ mean the same?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Isn't that the big O - as it's in the name of the article? This is why I've asked about the $O(x^4)$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics